# Hide TabBar when push

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uitabbar

I have two controller, main and detail, embed with navigationController and TabBarController; now I need to hide TabBar when performing the segue; I tried:

- in main controller adding `controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` in preparefor(segue9 method;
- in detail controller adding `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`;
- in main controller adding `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

But no one solve my problem.
How could I hide the TabBar and then make it visible when users touch navigationController back button?

Answer (score 1):

show tabBar

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

hide tabBar

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by the Interface Builder:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hook up your **tabBar** in your ViewController so you can reference it.

Then:

You can simply use this in your ViewDidLoad() method.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

Or you can change z position of tab bar this way:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -1
```

and if you want to show it again then:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = 0
```